# How to find info of the environment "I'm" deployed in

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration

I'm running an application on elastic beanstalk.

How do I find my application name? in other words, how does the application runnning in elastic beanstalk find out information about itself.

or other information about the environment the that the current application is runnning in.

I wouldn't be surprised if some of this information is available via system properties.

**UPDATE:** something I forgot to mention (sorry). It's java app and I'd prefer to use the JAVA SDK to acquire this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query Metadata about the instance by navigating from the instance to this internal address:

http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

There are many different methods you can use to query and parse the results of this data for your purposes.

See more information about [Instance Metadata and Userdata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, and rather nasty have to find the name of the environment is to check the root folder of the Elastic Beanstalk instance. As of today, there is a file there named `/<aws-env-name>_LaunchFile` in the root folder of the EC2 instance (**caveat emptor:** this can change at any time).

For example, if you environment name is "mycoolapp-dev" then there will be a file called `mycoolapp-dev_LaunchFile` in the root directory of your Elastic Beanstalk Instance. For things like [loggly](https://www.loggly.com/) and [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/) to work correctly, sometimes it's useful to give your host a proper hostname (both services still record the IP, which is the original EC2 IP).

The command snippet below can be pasted into your `.ebextensions` folder `.config` file to set the hostname to `mycoolapp-dev` for these services to work.

```
commands:
    00_set_hostname:
        command: "hostname `ls /*_LaunchFile | sed -e 's/\/\(.*\)_LaunchFile$/\1/'`"
```

Or a really nice solution is to use [this link by Steel Pangolin](https://steelpangolin.wordpress.com/2015/01/30/how-to-find-the-name-of-an-elastic-beanstalk-environment-from-inside-one-of-its-instances/) - [Jeremy Ehrhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070571/jeremy-ehrhardt)